# Texturing / UV Mapping doesn't unwrap properly

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

After trying to do this, I got a first model made in the hammer editor and I had issues to apply any textures what so ever I tried to just recreate the items in blender by using the original as measurements. Now the issue is that when I try to get a UV Map, it gets all scrambled and pushed in one corner.

[image: Example of one part of it]

When I try to paint it applies the color everywhere although it shouldn't. :C
Any tips or things I have to take care of or on what to avoid doing?

Here a picture of the model itself.
[image]

Edit:

Here a second attempts to make something more simple for blender to unwrap. I created a frame with 4 cubes that got stretched and joined. 2 of the 4 cubes got 2 sides removed each to remove unnecessary faces.

However the UV map still is fubar.
When I try to manually unwrap it I don't know how to align them properly since it's all a mess. :C

Any tips or or good tutorials you can recommend to understand what is going on here?

[image: UV map and Model view]

BTW the other two bares were created with a single block and extrusion.

Comment: Hello :). Please upload an image of your UV map, so we can see what exactly you're talking about. You can also [upload you file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), to check for possible issues.

Comment: Which method of mesh unwrapping have you used?

Comment: Looks like automatic unwrapping to me. Use manual unwrapping instead. Try to imagine how and where you would cut the lines in order to create a paper cut model.

Comment: I added a picture to show you what the uv map look like all the time.

Comment: Hello :). It seems your UV map isn't updated. Here is a [great tutorial on UV unwrapping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k&t=11s) by the BlenderGuru himself. Good luck.

Comment: Thx @JachymMichal. Will have a look. Funny thing is it was on one of my playlists but I haven't watched it yet. haha ^^'